# Присвоить в значение свойства объекта значение другого свойства

Tags: angularjs

Имеется объект

```
$scope.menu = [
    { 
        itemName: 'assets', 

        href: itemName,
    }     
];
```

Как в свойство `href` передать значение свойства `itemName`?

Comment: `$scope.menu = [
    { 
        itemName: 'assets', 

        href: 'assets',
    }     
];`

Comment: а зачем вы хотите это сделать?

Comment: Предположим у меня цмс и я хочу добавить новый пункт меню из админки. Я задаю его имя а ссылка автоматически генерируется из имени.

Comment: в предоставленном коде проще всего сделать как я показа в комментарии выше, если у вас другая ситуация - нужно рассматривать конкретно ее.

Comment: Смысл в том, чтоб не вручную забивать строку, а чтоб значение подставлялось программно, в зависимости от значения другого свойства.

Comment: так что мешает во время редактирования одного свойства обновить и второе? Если верить тегу - вы используете ангуляр, а там это повсеместно втыкивается. Поэтому и нужен конкретно ваш пример, а не какой-то абстрактный код.

Comment: вот так, например: `href = itemName = 'assets';` вы же не показываете как именно вы редактируете. Собственно вы ничего не показали как это должно работать.

Comment: Приведите пример кода и разметки, как вы хотите использовать, что получать и что имеете сейчас и не работает или работает не так как вы ожидали

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.menu = [
    { 
        itemName: 'assets', 

        href: $scope.menu[0].itemName,
    }     
];
```

Comment: не сработает, `$scope.menu` - массив, у него нет свойства _itemName_

Comment: не сработает, потому что это `$scope.menu[0].itemName` выполняется еще до того, как инициализируется `$scope.menu`  ;)